# the derivative of tangential vector is normal vector - can anyone please prove this?

Tags: calculus

I can see that, the derivative of tangential vector is normal vector i.e the second derivative is normal to the first derivative. but I couldn't derive a proof for it. can anyone please prove this? thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't this require that you use unit length tangent vectors?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a proof, but you can imagine the unit tangent vector function T as a position vector (i.e. tail at the origin) in which case its tip lies on the unit sphere. So the derivative of T, being tangent to the path of T, is tangent to the unit sphere, which is normal to T since T is a radius of the sphere. So the derivative of T is perpendicular to T by virtue of T being (constantly) a unit vector.